# How to update Chart.js based on dropdown list?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, charts, chart.js

**UPDATED**

**I have added a dropdown to my chart** which allows the user to select among the available operator names.
**I need your help so that when selecting an available operator name, the graphic is updated showing only the information of the selected operator.**

[image: grafico de ordenes]

From all my JSON response, for this example it should only show the information in a red box:

[image: json]

As you can see in the image, **if I select the Luis operator, this graph should update and show me only the Luis operator (he has 2 work orders in finished state).**

Below **my report.js file which I use to make the graph.**

**getChartData () method:**

I use ajax, basically I'm getting the data and loading my select with the names of the available operators.

**renderChart () method:**
 
I am passing it as a parameter "label and data" with these parameters I can make my graph also I am configuring some available options.

**select.on ('change', function ():**

**here I do not understand how to tell my chart to update depending on the option selected, then I would have to call the renderChart method again to graph again with the selected data but it does not work, I do not know how to solve it, it is what I am trying.**

**report.js**

```
function getChartData(user) {    
    $.ajax({
         url: '/admin/reports/getChart/' + user,
        type: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {             
            console.log(response);
            var data = [];
            var labels = [];         

            for (var i in response.orders) {

                data.push(response.orders[i].orders_by_user);
                labels.push(response.orders[i].name);  
                $("#operator").append('<option value='+response.orders[i].id+'>'+response.orders[i].name+'</option>');    
            }   
            renderChart(data, labels);              
        },

        error: function (response) {        
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}

function renderChart(data, labels) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("orders").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Terminadas',
                data: data,
                borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                backgroundColor: "#229954",
                borderWidth: 1,
                yAxisID: 'Ordenes',
                xAxisID: 'Operarios',
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    id: "Ordenes",
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true

                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Ordenes'
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    id: "Operarios",
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Operarios'
                    }

                }],
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Ordenes en estado terminado"
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom',
                labels: {
                  fontColor: "#17202A",
                }
            },
        }
    });

    function updateChart() {       
        myChart.destroy();     
        myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: document.getElementById("operator").value,
            data: data
        });
    };

}

getChartData();

$('#operator').select2({
    placeholder: 'Selecciona un operario',
    tags: false              
});


 var select = $('#operator'); 
 var pElem = document.getElementById('p')           

   select.on('change', function() {                
     var item = $(this).val();               
     pElem.innerHTML = 'selectedValue: ' + item;
     var data = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: data
     }
     var ctx = document.getElementById("orders").getContext('2d');
     var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
          type: 'line',
          data: data
        });
 });
```

My select:

```
<select class="form-control" name="operator" id="operator">
    <option></option>                                                            
</select>
```

**I get lost trying to link the selected option and the information to show (update the graph). Could you please tell me how to solve this?**

**UPDATED 1**

**My select:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="operator" id="operator">
    <option></option>                                                            
</select>
```

**Through ajax I load my select options:**

```
 for (var i in response.orders) {

   order.push(response.orders[i].orders_by_user);
   user.push(response.orders[i].name);              
   $("#operator").append('<option value='+response.orders[i].id+'>'+response.orders[i].name+'</option>');
 }      
 renderChart(order, user);
```

**With the answer you have given me, modify my report.js file exactly my `function renderChart(order, user)` and it is as follows:**

```
function renderChart(order, user) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("orders").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      //code...
    }); 

    //my select
    var selectOption = $('#operator');                    
    selectOption.on('change', function() {  

        var option = $("#operator").val();
        myChart.data.labels = option;
        if (option == 'All') {
           myChart.data.labels = user,
           myChart.data.datasets[0].data = order;
        } else {
          myChart.data.labels = option;
          myChart.data.datasets[0].data = order;
        }
        myChart.update();
    });            

}
```

**The graph is updated incorrectly an error occurs you can see it in the image:**

[image: option jose]

Obviously if I select the "All" option, it shows and graphs correctly, now if I select "jose" the following happens:

**The graph does not respect the scale, I know that Jose has only 1 work order, and up to 2 on the scale.**

**On the x axis instead of showing me the name in this case "Jose" is showing me the selection id which in this case is 6.**

**The same happens with the option "Miguel".**

Please help me correct this section:

```
var selectOption = $('#operator');                    
    selectOption.on('change', function() {  

        var option = $("#operator").val();
        myChart.data.labels = option;
        if (option == 'All') {
           myChart.data.labels = user,
           myChart.data.datasets[0].data = order;
        } else {
          myChart.data.labels = option;
          myChart.data.datasets[0].data = order;
        }
        myChart.update();
    });
```

Comment: **Could you please review select.on ('change', function () I am trying to update the chart with the selected option not working**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the selected options changes, you must not destroy the chart. All you need to do is performing the following steps.

1. Change the `data.labels`
2. Change the `data` of the unique dataset
3. Update the `chart` itself

This is basically done as follows.

```
myChart.data.labels = <new labels>;
myChart.data.datasets[0].data = <new values>;
myChart.update();
```

The following example illustrates how this can be done in JavaScript.

```js
orders = [
  { name: 'Luis', orders_by_user: '2' },
  { name: 'Jose', orders_by_user: '1' },
  { name: 'Miguel', orders_by_user: '3' }
];

const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('orders'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: orders.map(o => o.name),
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Terminadas',
      data: orders.map(o => o.orders_by_user),
      borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
      backgroundColor: "#229954",
      borderWidth: 1,
      yAxisID: 'Ordenes',
      xAxisID: 'Operarios',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: "Ordenes",
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 1
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Ordenes'
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        id: "Operarios",
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Operarios'
        }

      }],
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Ordenes en estado terminado"
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'bottom',
      labels: {
        fontColor: "#17202A",
      }
    },
  }
});

orders.forEach(o => {
  const opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = o.name;
  opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.name));
  document.getElementById('operator').appendChild(opt);
});

function refreshChart(name) {
  myChart.data.labels = [name];
  if (name == 'All') {
     myChart.data.labels = orders.map(o => o.name),
     myChart.data.datasets[0].data = orders.map(o => o.orders_by_user);
  } else {
    myChart.data.labels = [name];
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = orders.find(o => o.name == name).orders_by_user;
  }
  myChart.update();
}
```

```html
Operarios:
<select id="operator" onchange="refreshChart(this.value)">
    <option>All</option>                                                            
</select> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="orders" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: **Please check my update 1 the graph is updated incorrectly, with your help I can solve the problem**

Comment: @Rdrigo Ruiz: The main problem is the `value` assignments when you create the `<option>` elements. You use the order `id` instead of the `name`: `$("#operator").append('<option value='+response.orders[i].id+'>'...`

Comment: I understand I solve it by placing this: ''orders.forEach(o => {
  const opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = o.name;
  opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.name));
  document.getElementById('operator').appendChild(opt);
});''

Comment: **The truth is that I try and I can not solve it, could you give me an answer, following my code?**