# How to update Chart.js according to the option selected from my drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, chart.js

**I am trying to update my chart based on the option selected from my drop down list.**

**This is my JSON response:**

```
{
"orders": [
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Luis",
"orders_by_user": 2,
"rol": 2
},
{
"id": 6,
"name": "Jose",
"orders_by_user": 1,
"rol": 2
},
{
"id": 7,
"name": "Miguel",
"orders_by_user": 1,
"rol": 2
}
]
}
```

**Through ajax I obtain the data to make the graph and upload options to my drop-down list.
A little snippet of code:**

```
success: function (response) {             
            console.log(response);
            var order = [];
            var user = [];         

            for (var i in response.orders) {

                order.push(response.orders[i].orders_by_user);
                user.push(response.orders[i].name);              
                $("#operator").append('<option value='+response.orders[i].id+'>'+response.orders[i].name+'</option>');

            }      

            renderChart(order, user);
```

My Select:

```
<select class="form-control" name="operator" id="operator" >
    <option>All</option>                                                            
</select>
```

With this I get the selected text from my drop-down list.

```
    var selectOption = $('#operator');                    
    selectOption.on('change', function() {   
        var option = $("option:selected", selectOption).text();
```

**So if the selected option is "Luis", the graph would have to be updated graphing with the information that corresponds to "Luis" (see JSON response)**

This is how I try to update my chart:

```
function renderChart(order, user) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("orders").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      //code...
    }); 

    //my select
    var selectOption = $('#operator');                    
    selectOption.on('change', function() {  

         var option = $("option:selected", selectOption).text();
        myChart.data.labels = option;
        if (option == 'All') {
           myChart.data.labels = user,
           myChart.data.datasets[0].data = order;
        } else {
          myChart.data.labels = option;
          myChart.data.datasets[0].data = order;
        }
        myChart.update();
    });            

}
```

I think my problem is here:

```
} else {
    myChart.data.labels = option;
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = order;
 }
```

**The logic is if option is not equal to 'All',
then
myChart.data.labels = "Luis";
and myChart.data.datasets [0] .data = "2";**

How can I go back through my user and order array?
**Exactly in user are all the names of the operators and in order are the quantities of completed orders that correspond.**

Could you please guide me to solve this problem?

**ACTUALIZADO 1**

I am following this example, it is what I need.

**But it happens that my data for the graph is obtained through ajax and in this example the array is already defined.**

**Understanding this here is my confusion as I go through my user array and my order array again (see snippet of ajax code), correctly traversing these arrays I could apply the result in my if, else.**

```js
orders = [
  { name: 'Luis', orders_by_user: '2' },
  { name: 'Jose', orders_by_user: '1' },
  { name: 'Miguel', orders_by_user: '1' }
];



const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('orders'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: orders.map(o => o.name),
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Terminadas',
      data: orders.map(o => o.orders_by_user),
      borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
      backgroundColor: "#229954",
      borderWidth: 1,
      yAxisID: 'Ordenes',
      xAxisID: 'Operarios',
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: "Ordenes",
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          stepSize: 1
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Ordenes'
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        id: "Operarios",
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Operarios'
        }

      }],
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Ordenes en estado terminado"
    },
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'bottom',
      labels: {
        fontColor: "#17202A",
      }
    },
  }
});

orders.forEach(o => {
  const opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = o.name;
  opt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(o.name));
  document.getElementById('operator').appendChild(opt);
});

function refreshChart(name) {
  myChart.data.labels = [name];
  if (name == 'All') {
     myChart.data.labels = orders.map(o => o.name),
     myChart.data.datasets[0].data = orders.map(o => o.orders_by_user);
  } else {
    myChart.data.labels = [name];
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = orders.find(o => o.name == name).orders_by_user;
  }
  myChart.update();
}
```

```html
Operarios:
<select id="operator" onchange="refreshChart(this.value)">
    <option>All</option>                                                            
</select> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="orders" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Related Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019167/how-to-update-chart-js-based-on-dropdown-list

Comment: @EzraSiton Siton  If I can not find a solution, I really try but I can not update the graph depending on the option selected, could you help me?

Comment: Please add a minimal code example (add snippet) - your Q is more a "story". Remove all the ajax and complex examples. Your main problem related to the "all" button (Show all data) - or to change data from `Luis` to `Jose`?

Comment: @Ezra Siton if I select (all) it obviously graphs correctly, now if I select (luis) it should graph in labels "luis" and data "2". basically the problem is in the part (else)

Comment: @EzraSiton Siton Please check my update carefully 1.
Could you help me solve the problem

Comment: Ok. I saw your code snippet. But what is the problem (Be more clear. Sorry "when i click X i want Y" and so on).

Comment: @EzraSiton  my code snippet is an example, doing it this way is easy, instead I get the data through ajax My problem is when I want to update my graph. If I select all the graph is displayed and graph correctly. So if works. instead the else is not working, the else is the problem. For example if I select Luis: in data.labels I have to show luis, and in data.data I have to show 2

Comment: @EzraSiton ```} else {
    myChart.data.labels = option;
    myChart.data.datasets[0].data = order;
 }```