# donut chart not rendering with csv data chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to create a donut chart with chart.js using data from csv file. Following is my script so far, but it is not working. Any guidance is appreciated on the same.

```
<script>
var file='donut.csv';
d3.csv(file).then(makeChart); //use d3.csv to read file
function makeChart(types){
var can=types.map(function(d){return d.cancelled});
var suc=types.map(function(d){return d.success});
var fa=types.map(function(d){return d.failed});
 {
var chart=new Chart(document.getElementById("doughnut-chart"), {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ["Cancelled","Success", "Failed"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Population (millions)",
          backgroundColor: ["#3e95cd", "#3cba9f","#8e5ea2"],
          data: [can,suc,fa]
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Weekly  Status'
      }
    }
}
}
);
</script>
```

and my donut.csv looks like as below:

```
cancelled,300,
success,1000,
failed,20,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `CSV` data has no header, you should use [`d3.text`](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#text) to load the data, followed by [`d3.csvParseRows`](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/master/README.md#dsv_parseRows) to parse it to a `JSON` array (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13870360/2358409). To extract the data values from the `JSON` array, you can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
data: d3.csvParseRows(types).map(v => v[1])
```

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
d3.text("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uminder/testdata/main/so/csv/donut.csv").then(makeChart);
function makeChart(types) {
  new Chart('doughnut-chart', {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
      labels: ['Cancelled', 'Success', 'Failed'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Population (millions)',
        backgroundColor: ['#3e95cd', '#3cba9f', '#8e5ea2'],
        data: d3.csvParseRows(types).map(v => v[1])
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Weekly  Status'
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="doughnut-chart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Uminder for improved code and pointing the missing piece. If you do not mind, plesae can you tell me in case my csv changes, how do I update chart with new data ?  calling just update() function ?

Comment: @Novice: Please take a look at the following answers that deal with `chart.update()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61025107/2358409 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61576710/2358409