# Charts with previous data appear when hovering the cursor over the chart in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm having a weather website where you can type city's name and it will display the weather data from OpenWeatherAPI. I also have a chart made using Chart.js. There's however a problem, when I search other cities, the chart updates but when I hover the cursor over some points each previous chart suddenly appears instead of the current chart with every new mouse hover. I tried using the update() and destroy() method before updating the chart but it doesn't seem to help.

I have my canvas object inside a div called chartContainer and it's the only child of chartContainer div.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: arrayDates,
        datasets: [
            {
                borderColor: '#69CDE6',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(12, 176, 216, 0.1)',
                data: arrayTemps
            }
        ]
    },
    options:{
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: `Prognoza pogody dla ${citynCountry}`,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: 'bold'
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
        },
        scales:{
            yAxes:[{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Temperatura w °C',
                    fontSize: 16
                },
                ticks: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }],
            xAxes:[{
                display: true,
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'Data i godzina',
                    fontSize: 16
                },
                ticks: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }]

        }
    }

});
myChart.update();
```

Comment: What does `myChart.update();` do?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you're creating new charts within the same `canvas` each time the data changes. You should better create the chart once only and then update its `data.labels`, `data.datasets.data` and `options.title` each time the data for other cities are available. After all `data` and `options` are updated, you need to invoke [`myChart.update()`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html).

Please take a look at the following answers that deal with similar issues:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61025107/2358409
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61576710/2358409